# "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" while trying to fetch day of the week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am getting the following error while trying to fetch the particular days of the week. The code which I have used is mentioned below:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofweek
```

The date is in the following format.

[image]

But, I am not able to fetch the following days of the week and is getting an error as follows:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling that the .dt accessor can only be used with 'datetimelike' values. Unfortunately your **question is incomplete** since you are not showing us the dtype of the 'Date' column, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But if the dtype isn't 'datetime64[ns]' I take from your painting that it must be 'object' (string).

Solution: Convert object into datetime and then use the .dt accessor:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.dayofweek
```

The result in your example is all zero, because 2005-07-25 was a Monday.